# Additionally hyphenation rules like in InDesign

Tags: packages, babel, hyphenation, polyglossia

Is there a package or some penalty setting to control the hyphenation points of a word?

In InDesign for example you could define that a word should only be broken after x letters (see [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/text-composition.html#hyphenate_text) under `Set automatic hyphenation options for a paragraph` Point 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent hyphenation of words *before* their respective fourth letter, say, just insert the instruction

```
\lefthyphenmin4
```

(For English-language documents, one usually works with `\lefthyphenmin2` and `\righthyphenmin3`.)

Comment: Thank you. Are there more of these options? Some of the options available in InDesign are also useful like no hyphenation of last word in paragraph or no x hyphenations in a row.

Comment: @user2653422 - Chapter H of the TeXbook presents TeX's hyphenation-related routines and macros. The penalties `\finalhyphendemerits` and `\doublehyphendemerits` let you control (and, in particular, prevent) the occurrence of hyphenation on the next-to-last line of a paragraph and of consecutive lines that end with hyphenated words.